# Git create patch for unpushed changes in other branch without checkout/switch

Tags: git, github

I need to create backup for all committed(but not pushed) changes in other branch.

I have 3 branches

```
C:\develop\V1001-git>git branch
* V1900
  V2000
  v2001
```

I have multiple branches in my repository. Now when I do `git format-patch origin/V1900` then I get the patches created for my committed but not pushed changes,
but when I try to do it for other branch without switching to that branch for example

`git format-patch origin/V2000`

It starts creating patches for all the changes in the branch including the pushed one, which I dont want. I just want the committed but not pushed changes. Could you please help me with some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation ([`git help format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch)) mentions :

> There are two ways to specify which commits to operate on.
>
> 1. A single commit, , specifies that the commits leading to the tip of the current branch that are not in the history that leads to the  to be output.
> 2. Generic  expression (see "SPECIFYING REVISIONS" section in gitrevisions[7]) means the commits in the specified range.

Run : `git format-patch origin/V2000..V2000`

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine for me! Have a great day!

Comment: Glad it helped. If this answers your question, please tick it as "answered", to indicate to other readers that this question has a solution.